# Distinct differentiable structures?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I want to show that 2 maximal atlases on $\mathbb{R}$ are distinct. Define 
$$ \phi_r(t)=\begin{cases}
t & t\leq0 \\
rt & t\geq0
\end{cases}
$$

Now make two maximal atlases; one from $(\mathbb{R},\phi_r)$, and the other from $(\mathbb{R},\phi_s)$ where we have that $0<r<s$.

I know that on the real line as we usually have it, neither of $\phi_r,\phi_s$ would be smooth, but because we make a differentiable structure from them they now count as being smooth. But how can I show that they are incompatible?

From my understanding, if we compose one of them with the inverse of the other we will get for example 
$$\phi_s\circ\phi_r^{-1}(\phi_r(\mathbb{R}))=\begin{cases} t & t\leq0 \\
\frac{s}{r}t & t\geq0.
\end{cases}$$
as a mapping from $\phi_r(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Now this shouldn't be smooth, but I don't understand how I can reason that that is the case because we built the differentiable structures from these two maps. I think I am just slightly lost with some of the detailed specifics of what I have to show. Would anybody be able to clarify the nuance that I am missing?

Comment: Do you mean "the other from $(\mathbb{R},\phi_\color{red}{s})$"?

Comment: I did, edited now

Comment: By definition, you need to check that the transition map $\phi_s\circ\phi_r^{-1}$  is not smooth in the natural smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}$, which is $(\mathbb{R},\text{id})$.